# MVC ViewModel HttpPost return value has null values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I spent some time on this problem. I'm passing a ViewModel back from my View to the Controller via a form HttpPost. However, only SelectedItemId has value. Users and Rights are null.

**View model UserRightViewModel**

```
public class UserRightViewModel
{
    public string SelectedItemId { get; set; }

    public SelectList Users;

    public List<RightViewModel> Rights { get; set; }
}
```

**View model RightsViewModel**

```
public class RightsViewModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name{ get; set; }

    public bool isSelected { get; set; }    
}
```

**Controller Post**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Index(UserRightsViewModel _viewModel)
{
   UserRightsViewModel viewModel = _viewModel;
   /*value _viewModel = null for Users and Rights
   /* code stuff */
   return View(viewModel);
}
```

**View**

```
@model Web.ViewModels.UserRightsViewModel
     @using (Html.BeginForm())
     {
         @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
        <section class="content-header">
            <h1>
                @ViewBag.Title
            </h1>
            @*<ol class="breadcrumb">
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Examples</a></li>
                    <li class="active">Blank page</li>
                </ol>*@
        </section>

        <!-- Main content -->
        <section class="content">

            <!-- Default box -->
            <div class="box">
                <div class="box-header with-border">

                    <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Collapse">
                            <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
                        </button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="remove" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Remove">
                            <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>

        <br />
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectedItemId, "User", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedItemId, Model.Users, new { onchange = "redirect(this.value)", @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedItemId)
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br />

          <div class="box-body">

                    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Rights.Count(); i += 2)
                    {
                        <div class="row form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <div class="col-md-6">

                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Rights.ElementAt(i).isSelected, new { @class = "checkbox checkbox-center" })
                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Rights.ElementAt(i).isSelected, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-8">

                                        @Model.Rights.ElementAt(i).Denumire
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <div class="col-md-6">

                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Rights.ElementAt(i + 1).isSelected, new { @class = "checkbox checkbox-center" })
                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Rights.ElementAt(i + 1).isSelected, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-8">
                                        @Model.Rights.ElementAt(i + 1).Name
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    }
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="col-md-9">

                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Index", null, new { @class = "btn btn-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
               </div>
        </section>
    </div>
}
```

I have no idea why some values are null. Why some of values are sent and some not?

Comment: Your view says `UserDrepturiViewModel` and your code is `UserRightViewModel`...

Comment: I've set up a demo here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/aC7AJp

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari i still cannot figure out what is wrong in my set up

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari your demo is not working with post call.

Comment: Do you use Data Annotation to make model validation

Comment: @hasan i do not use

Comment: For those who down vote please leave a simple comment. Be more creative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Users` is `null` because your not (and nor should you) creating and input for each property of each `SelectListItem` in the `SelectList` (if you need to return the view you re-populate the value in the POST method). And in any case, its a field, not a property (has no `{ get; set; }`) so the `DefaultModelBinder` cannot set it).

`Rights` is null because you cannot use `.ElementAt()` to generate form controls for a collection (inspect the html your generating and you will see that the `name` attributes have no relationship to your model). The name attributes need to be

```
<input name="Rights[0].ID" ... />
<input name="Rights[0].Name" ... />
<input name="Rights[0].isSelected" ... />
<input name="Rights[1].ID" ... />
<input name="Rights[1].Name" ... />
<input name="Rights[1].isSelected" ... />
....
```

Note that your only generating a for control for the `isSelected` property which on its own would be meaningless in the POST method and you will an least want to include a hidden input for the `ID` property.

It appears from your code that you want to generate a 2 column layout, in which case your code should be (simplified)

```
<div class="row form-group">
    @for(int i = 0; i < Model.Rights.Count; i++)
    {
        <div class="col-md-6">
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Rights[0].ID)
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Rights[0].isSelected)
        </div>
        // End current 'row' and start a new one every 2nd item
        if ((i + 1) % 2 == 0)
        {
            @:</div><div class="row form-group">
        }
    }
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. It is works! With the mention that `m.Rights[0] -> m.Rights[i]` and had to add  `@Model.Rights.ElementAt(i).Name` after `@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Rights[0].isSelected)` because no name of checkbox was seen.

Answer (score 0):

Hi here is answer for your doubt, some values are posting and some values are not.

Actually you are getting the correct result and everything works perfectly

I said this because, if you bind selectedid and selectlistitem to the dropdownlistfor helper, then you will get only selectedid which was assigned as a name for the dropdownlist control. so when post, browser has sent name value pair.

This is same reason for checkbox also , which property has binded to the name that only you will get it in the post.

Hope above information was helpful

Thanks

Karthik

Answer (score -1):

I can see you put submit button outside form. so form not submitting property.